# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() vue js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file, laravel-8, laravel-controller

I cannot upload multiple images in my Laravel + vue js project..

here is my code below

my vue conponent

```
<form @submit.prevent="addProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <label for="product_image">Product Image:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <input type="file" name="pics[]" id="product_image" @change="fieldChange" multiple>
                                            <has-error :form="form" field="product_image"></has-error>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <img :src="form.product_image" height="70px" width="85px" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

</form>
```

i Used FormData to upload images

```
    data: function(){
            return{
                attachment:[],
                imageForm : new FormData,
            }
        },
        methods:{
            fieldChange(e){
                let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
                if (!selectedFiles.length) {
                    return false;
                }
                for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;i++){
                    this.attachment.push(selectedFiles[i])
                }
                console.log(this.attachment);
                 //I checked here ang got image arrays
            },
            addProduct:function(){
                for(let i=0;i<this.attachment.length;i++){

                this.imageForm.append('pics[]',this.attachment[i]);

                //When I console.log() this line it says undefined
                }
                axios.post('/save-product',this.form,this.imageForm).then((response)=>{
                        toastr.success('Product Info Added Successfully','Success!');
                    }).catch((error)=>{

                    })
            },
}
```

my controller here...here I find this error

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uploadedFiles = $request->pics;
        foreach ($uploadedFiles as $file) {
            $file->store(public_path('uploads/products'));
        }
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success'],200);
}
```

status says 500 error...and in my network I got that error...And says Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

this is my full part of data..

```
data: function(){
            return{
                form: new Form({
                    product_name:null,
                    product_color:null,
                    publication_status:1,
                    category_id:'',
                    brand_name:null,
                    product_price_regular:null,
                    product_price_discount:null,
                    product_quantity:1,
                    short_description:null,
                    long_description:null,
                    user_name:'Admin',
                    // product_image:[],
                }),
                attachments:[],
                imageForm : new FormData,
            }
        },
```

please see this part
when I do this other fields saved in database but images do not save...
and if i do not add these fields images are saved in database

```
addProduct(){
                for(let i=0;i<this.attachments.length;i++){
                this.imageForm.append('product_image[]',this.attachments[i]);
                }
                const data = {
                    'product_image':this.product_image,'product_name':this.product_name,'product_color':this.product_color,'category_id':this.category_id,'product_price_regular':this.product_price_regular,'product_price_discount':this.product_price_discount,'short_description':this.short_description,'long_description':this.long_description,'user_name':this.user_name,'publication_status':this.publication_status
                }
                const config= {
           headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                   } 
                }
                axios.post('/save-product',data,this.imageForm,config).then((response)=>{
                        toastr.success('Product Info Added Successfully','Success!');
                    }).catch((error)=>{

                    })
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first. Axios parameters are not correctly passed. Axios expects first parameter as route path, second the form data and third is header. Therefor just modify your axios code like below and it will work.

```
 const config= {
           headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                   } 
        }
    this.imageForm.append('product_name',this.product_name);
    this.imageForm.append('product_color',this.product_color);

    axios.post('/save-product',this.imageForm,config).then((response)=>{
              toastr.success('Product Info Added Successfully','Success!');
            }).catch((error)=>{

            })
```

I also attached the laravel response image to show that it is working fine.
[image]

Comment: this works perfectly...but how to change directory to public path???

Comment: Dear did you tried the laravel asset function ? 
e.g asset('profiles/image.png')

Comment: no.Can I do it in my controller???
and an addition please...
when I submit this form by FormData axios.post('/') did it.But how do I upload other fields when I want to upload them by v-form.

Comment: public function uploadFile($path,...$files){
        $path = ltrim($path,'/');
       
        foreach ($files as  $file){

            $orginalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $newName = time().'_'.$orginalName;
             
            $file->move(public_path().'/'.$path,$newName);

        }
    }

Assume that you have folder profiles inside public directory then just pass file and the path like below.

uploadFile('profiles',$file);

you can also pass array of files in second argument

Comment: bind v-modal to input field and on submit of form append that values with key. e.g

<input type="username" v-model="username"/>

this.imageForm.append('username',this.username)

Comment: do I need to import all my input fields in this.imageForm.append()  ???

Comment: create variables in data section for each input field. For example you have another field username. Then inside data section, create a variable like username:''. Then bind that to input field. e.g <input type="text" v-model="username"/> and right before the api call append this variable with key inside formData like this.imageForm.append('username', username)

Comment: Dear  I don't have much better experience of using v-form API. As far i know its for validation form by using rules. However, its always good practice to create object with all form values and then pass with axios like.

const data = {
'pics':this.pics,
'username':this.username
}

and then in axios using axios.post(route,data, config)

Comment: I updated my question...please save me this time

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Ow I need to append then separately ...I never worked with this style...I always used vform...Thank you again...May ALLAH bless you